# Developing a UI for a SpriteKit game

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, sprite-kit

I am developing a game in Spritekit which has multiple scenes.  On one of the scenes I would like to display a menu to allow the user to pick "resources" or "units" to place on the scene. I want a window for the user to pick the "resources"  I know I can add iOS UI elements onto the scene, however I don't want standard iOS look and feel for a button, listbox etc.

Some guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not a good question to ask as it is mostly based on opinion and too broad.

Comment: I've edited my question to make it more focused

Comment: You can use custom images in most UI elements like buttons, scrollView, etc... As such you can customize the feel and look to be in tune with your game's theme.

Answer (score 0):

see this : 
In this tutorial you will find an answer i think : 
http://willieshi.com/post/75337350713/making-a-game-menu-with-sprite-kit-tutorial-01

there is a lot of tutorials in the google .... just wrote sprite kit menu tutorial ....

Comment: Thanks - I have googled and while there are plenty of sprite kit tutorials I have yet to find one that effectively explains how I can achieve what I need.